# What material is the shroud of keglands counter flow chiller made of?

Tags: equipment, wort-chiller, plastic

The specification only says "pliable polymer", but exactly what is it made of?

To be more specific I would like to know what temperature it can handle? Is it food grade? If it's food grade, to which temperature is it food grade? Ie can I run boiling hot water through the water path? And then use the water afterwards?

Comment: Wouldn't the fact that it is a chiller of wort be already an indication that it can handle hot wort (100°C/212°F)?

Comment: @chthon However the wort is supposed to be fed into the inner copper pipe. I was asking abouth the outer shroud.

Answer (score 0):

[Q/A on williams](https://www.williamsbrewing.com/Home-Brewing-Equipment/Wort-Making-Equipment/Wort-Chillers/Keg-Land-Counterflow-Wort-Chiller) brewing reports this:

> The outer plastic hose cannot handle temperatures of over 150 degrees F.